# I need to read a specific range of date? What code should I use?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('COVID19.csv')

df_ex = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['location' ,'date', 'total_cases', 
'new_cases', 'total_deaths', 'new_deaths'])

df_ext = df_ex[df_ex.location.isin(['New Zealand', 'Cyprus'])]
```

with this code it gives me this output
[image: CLICK TO SEE THE OUTPUT PHOTO]

Now, I only need to read the date from a specific range. what code should I use?

Comment: What range for example? What are the conditions?

Comment: range= from april 2020 to october 2021. like that

Answer (score 0):

```
start_date = xxx
end_Date = yyy

dfrange = df.loc[(df['date'] > start_date) & (df['date'] <= end_date)]
```

if you wanna just one column as output:

```
dfrange = df.loc[(df['date'] > start_date) & (df['date'] <= end_date), total_deaths']
```

Comment: it doesn't work. it still gives the same output